# Can not get a subelement in a jQuery Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-blade

Good. evening. I have a Laravel 10 blade template, and in a certain point I am calling a jQuery Ajax function when a tab is clicked, I receiving an HTML response. but when I try to get a sub-element from that response it returns undefined. here is the HTML code, and the JavaScript function:

```html
@extends('layouts.base') @section('content')
<div class="payer-container" style="margin-top: 6%;">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-4 mx-4">
        <div class="card-header pb-0">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
            <div>
              <h5 class="my-6 font-weight-bold text-secondary">All Payable</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0 pb-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link has-outstanding active " data-tag="tag-content-1" id="tab-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="/payers/outstanding" role="tab" aria-selected="false">

                <span class="d-none d-sm-block font-weight-bold text-capitalized text-xs">Outstanding</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link has-payed" id="tab-2" data-tag="tag-content-2" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="/payers/payed" role="tab" aria-selected="true">

                <span class="d-none d-sm-block font-weight-bold text-capitalized text-xs">Payed</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table align-items-center mb-0 table-hover table-align-middle w-100">


          </div>



          <thead class="table-light">

            <tr>
              <th class="text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7">
                Reference #
              </th>
              <th class="text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7">
                Due date
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7">
                Company name
              </th>
              <th class="text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7 ps-2">
                Initial amount
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7">
                Outstanding amount
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalized text-secondary text-xxs font-weight-bolder opacity-7">
                Options
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>


            <div class="tab-content" style="visibility: visible">
              @if ($payments) @foreach ($payments as $payment)
              <tr>
                <td class="ps-4">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ $payment["reference_id"] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td class="ps-4">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{ $payment["due_date"] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-capitalized mb-0">{{ $payment["creditor_id"] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-left">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{$payment["currency"]}} {{ $payment["initial_amount"] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-bold mb-0">{{$payment["currency"]}} {{ $payment["outstanding_amount"] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <p class="text-xs font-weight-light mb-0">
                    <i class="fa fa-download"> <a href=""></a></i> @if ($payment['status'] == 'unPaid')
                    <button class="payer-button" type="submit" style="width: auto; padding:2px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ff6321; color: white;">Pay Now</button> @endif
                  </p>
                </td>

              </tr>
              @endforeach @endif
            </div>






          </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

---

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
  $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  let url = $(this).attr('href');
  let tabContentElement = $('.payer-container');
  $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: url
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      let newContent = $(response).filter('.tab-content').html();
      alert(newContent);
      tabContentElement.html(newContent);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("Error");
    });

  return false;
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Comment: `.filter` won't give you a "sub-element" - try `$(response).find(".tab-content").html()`

Comment: Also, your HTML is all kinds of messed-up, invalid structure.   So even if it does find it, it's unlikely to have the content you expect.   (unless [tag:laravel-blade] does something different with `<div>` elements)

Comment: `$('.payer-container').load(\`${url} .tab-content\`)` could replace the whole AJAX part

Comment: I already tried using find() method and it returns undefined in newContent.

Comment: Then to help you more, we'd need to see an example of `response`.  See [mcve]

Comment: @freedomn-m, teh response that came in was this: https://pastebin.com/HZTDvbNa

Comment: I had to put it in console.log() as it was too bit for alert, created pastebin.

Comment: Your issue is that you have `<html>` which jquery isn't expecting so the "only" element jquery sees is the `<head>` element which doesn't have `.tab-content`.   You can put your html into an in-memory div and then it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4b6d12kf/

Comment: @freedomn-m and how would I do that?

Comment: `$("<div>").html(response).find(".tab-content")`